# How to resize an actual size of image in android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, image-resizing

My app goes to the gallery and the user picks an image then return to onActivityResult method in my activity where i got file path of the image. I can get the bitmap's height and width by implementing:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
int height = options.outHeight;
int width = options.outWidth;
```

Now, If the bitmap has width greater than 500 px, I need to resize the image to have a max width of 500 px, and the scale down the height. This is the formula that I will use for scaling the height down:

```
        int origWidth = width;
        int origHeight = height;
        int destHeight, destWidth;

        if (origWidth <= 500 || origHeight <= 500) {
            destWidth = origWidth;
            destHeight = origHeight;
        } else {
            destWidth = 500;
            destHeight = (origHeight * destWidth) / origWidth;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.create(/*bitmap source*/, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
```

How can I create a bitmap, because the inJustDecodeBounds property is set to true, returning null for the bitmap object. And if I set it to false, picking image larger than the memory can hold will cause for OutOfMemory error.

Answer (score 0):

uses Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP")

This is a sample code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
// this will open all images in the Galery
intent.setDataAndType(photoUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
// this defines the aspect ration
intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectY);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectX);
// this defines the output bitmap size
intent.putExtra("outputX", sizeX);
intent.putExtra("outputY", xizeY);
// true to return a Bitmap, false to directly save the cropped iamge
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
//save output image in uri
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

Comment: Is the method will crop the image? or just resize it? I need to resize the image @Aditya

Comment: It will resize and will give you bitmap directly

Comment: How can I define my sizeX and sizeY?

Comment: first you can mentioned your aspect radio like 9:16 or 21:9 then give only sizeX. Based on sizeX and aspect radio, system will decide sizeY and your image will be automatically cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet to scale down an image if its width > 500.

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int reqWidth) {
    if (bitmap.getWidth() > reqWidth) {
        int height = reqWidth / bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight();

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, height, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return scaledBitmap;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```